# I don't think this can be done with cleartool find to get all LATEST for a file

Tags: find, version, cleartool

Basically I would like to do:

```
cleartool find . -version 'version(.../LATEST)' -print 
| egrep '\\.[CH]@@' 
| xargs -I {} grep 'TEXT' {} \;
```

But version requires a branch name if using `.../` and I want to get all branches for the files.

I know you can cheat and get all branches by using `-branch '\!attype(dummyname)'` but the branch name is only the first step.
I would like to be able to grep all of the `LATEST` versions on all of the branches and the main for -name '`*.[CH]`' files in the VOB.

I have made a script to use the above dummyname to get all branches, grep '`\\.[CH]@@`', append `LATEST` to it and grep that file name for what I am looking for but it is very slow to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this will be slow, and that the `-branch '\!attype(dummyname)'` seems to be the only way to list all branches, according to [IBM `cleartool find` examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425&wv=1).

I would try first to find all `*.ch` file versions, and sort that out per branches to isolates the latest. That might be quicker.